# write and append index of the nested loops in .csv file in rows python

Tags: python-3.x, nested

```
    for i in range(100,1500, 100):
        for j in np.arange(0,5, 0.5):
            for k in range(100,1500, 100):
                for l in np.arange(0,5,0.5):
                    for m in range(1000,10000, 500):
                        for n in range(0,20,2):
                            for _ in range(2500):  #take this as redundant
                                res=i+j+k+l+m+n
                                rew.append(res)
                            r1=rew[np.argmax(rew)]
```

```python
         i         j         k         l         m         n         r1        
         100       0         100       0         1000      0         1200      
         100       0         100       0         1000      2         1202      
         1200      1202      100       0         1000      4         1204      
         .         
         .         
         .         
         .         
         1500      5         1500      5         10000     20
```

I need to save this in .csv file in the format shown

Comment: nesting like this is a very inefficient. An ideal (ie. faster) method would be to make lists and parse them into a `pandas` dataframe and then use the `write_csv()` function to create the csv file.

Comment: Next time you post on stack overflow it is better to copy and paste your code into the stack overflow question rather than embedding a screen capture (`.PNG` or `.JPG`). You can force your code to display in a mono-space font by writing three apostrophes at the beginning and three apostrophes at the end. The apostrophe key on your computer's keyboard is usually in the upper-left hand corner, near the `1` key and `tab`

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 dataframe = {'i': [], 'j': [], 'k': [], 'l': [], 'm': [], 'n': [], 'r1':[]}

 df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)
```

Put this below line inside loop where you want to append

```
 df.loc[len(df.index)] = [i, j, k, l, m, n, res]
```

Put this below line outside of these loops

```
 df.to_csv("myfile.csv")
```